# Reinstall of 14.04 after somehow changing mbr to gpt

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, gparted

I had a functioning ubuntu 14.04 system that I upgraded to 16.04 and everthing seemed to be working fine until I somehow changed my partition ( I think) from mbr to gtp.

My computer won't boot even to the grub menu so since my /home is on a seperate partition I decided to reinstall ubuntu 14.04 without reformatting /home to get system back (as I've done before) The problem is that after selecting something else and formatting / as ext4 and setting /home as ext4 but not formatting it, I hit install now and got the following error which I've never seen before.

" The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for use as “Reserved BIOS boot area” and should be at least 1 MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition mounted on /boot. If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct this error, bootloader installation may fail later, although it may still be possible to install the boot loader to a partition."

Also there is small amounts of "free space" showing up between partitions in the install partition table.

Here is my current gparted [image: gparted]

and the installation type screen showing the free space and current device for bootloader installation [image: installation type]

Is there anything I can do to get back to a working ubuntu install, for instance if I shut down and boot to live CD again (to change from UEFI to BIOS somehow) have I wrecked everything by already formatting SDA5?

Edit /etc/fstab looks like

> overlay / overlay rw 0 0
>
> tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
>
> /dev/sda6 swap swap defaults 0 0

Also. Output of gdisk /dev/sda is

> GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8
>
> Partition table scan:
> MBR: protective
> BSD: not present
> APM: not present
> GPT: present
>
> Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Could I get back to mbr using gdisk? I could if MBR was present but I'm not sure with protective.

Comment: Does Windows still boot? Please edit your question to show us what /etc/fstab looks like. Is your BIOS set to UEFI or Legacy/Compatible? Cheers, Al

Comment: Windows does not boot. I edited the question to add that information and also the output of gdisk, thanks, Meabh

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if it's UEFI or Legacy and I'm too scared to restart the computer and check

Comment: You want it in UEFI mode. Also, what was in t he 359GiB unallocated partition? Also, see my answer, below. Cheers, Al

Comment: Nothing was in it, but the extended partition what used to contain sda5,6 and 7 seems to have dissapeared, I presume that is why I have 1 MiB of unallocated between sda6 and sda7. I have added the boot flag as per your answer below and will now reinstall grub and ubuntu. Does it matter which order I install them in? Meabh

Comment: Changing an extended partition that contained sda5/6/7 to primary partitions would be strange. Just reinstall Ubuntu into sda5, make sure to tell the installer that your /home is on sda7, and it should reinstall grub to /dev/sda for you. Cheers, Al

Comment: Also, should I edit the title to better describe the issue?

Comment: I don't think you can, but you can try. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussions in the comments...

You do/did have a GPT disk. The GPT has a built in `protective MBR` for compatibility.

I just looks like the `boot` flag may have disappeared from sda1. Use gparted to add that flag back. If the fstab that you posted came from sda5, then it's wrong... reinstall Ubuntu into sda5, and tell it that you've got /home in sda7, and it should put in a valid fstab, and reinstall grub so that you can dual-boot again.

Report back. Cheers, Al

Comment: I did this and initially it booted to a black screen with a flashing prompt but then I went to BIOS and changed from Legacy to UEFI, and the system booted to ubuntu, files intact, worked perfectly. Should I reinstall grub so I can see the option of booting to windows again as it booted directly to ubuntu?

Comment: The BIOS should have been in UEFI mode when you installed Ubuntu. You want Windows and Ubuntu installed in the same mode. Try booting while holding down the LEFT SHIFT key, and that should bring up the GRUB menu, where you should be able to select which OS to boot. Cheers, Al

Comment: It wasn't. Should I reinstall before proceeding? Thanks so much, Meabh

Comment: See if Windows boots first. Cheers, Al

Comment: I didn't get the option to boot it

Comment: Did the GRUB menu appear? Show me what your current /etc/fstab looks like. Cheers, Al

Comment: I got the GRUB menu back but there is no windows option on it, only Ubunu, Advanced options for Ubuntu and System settings

Comment: Imgur link to /etc/fstab http://imgur.com/SPHpCSa

Comment: fstab looks good now. Windows not booting may be because of the legacy/UEFI thing. Do you have a Windows install CD/DVD? In Ubuntu, install `boot-repair` using Synaptic. Run it and take the default fix choice, and lets see if it discovers the Windows partition and puts up a new GRUB menu. Cheers, Al

Comment: boot-repair told me to run it from a live-usb so I'm making one now. I have a windows 8 operating system disk which came with the computer but I'm worried it will wipe my ubuntu and I don't have any important files on windows so I'd much prefer to not wipe ubuntu.

Comment: Did you have Windows 8 installed before? If yes, we might end up using the Windows CD/DVD in repair mode to fix Windows... but it'll reinstall a Windows bootloader... overwriting GRUB... and you'll need the boot-repair flash that you're making now, to fix that. Cheers, Al

Comment: boot-repair gave me this error "GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option." Should I reinstall ubuntu on legacy?

Comment: I think it was windows 7, I didn't use it much though. I am very familar with the ubuntu install at this stage though, so it might be easier to install ubuntu again in Legacy somehow?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23256478/ The link to boot-repair information

Comment: Since you're able to boot Ubuntu now, I'd recommend **backing up your important files first**. Then flip your BIOS back to legacy and see if boot-repair will run from the flash key. I believe that we're fighting the legacy/UEFI thing now. It's possible that Windows got installed in legacy mode, and Ubuntu **looks** like it installed in UEFI mode. GPT disk formatting is required for 2TB disks. Cheers, Al

Comment: Flipping back to BIOS and running boot-repair generated the same error. I really appreciate your help with this. I suppose I'll have to reinstall windows as UEFI somehow.

Comment: I put the windows install disk in and it is a legacy disk. There was no CD option in UEFI, just ubuntu option.

Comment: **Add** the `esp` flag to sda1, and see if that changes anything. Try booting the usb boot-repair flash in UEFI mode, and if that doesn't work, try legacy mode. We want to try and get the boot-repair working, 'cause you may need it if you reinstall Windows. Search here for `boot-repair`, and learn how to run boot-repair from the Ubuntu Live DVD. Then try that. You get the idea. Play with it for a while, and let me know how you finally make out. Cheers, Al

Comment: Just realized, we could **add** the bios_grub flag, as boot-repair suggests. Cheers, Al

Comment: I added bios-grub flag but I added it to Sda1 then ran boot-repair , big mistake. Computer won't boot to anything, Red (!) beside that partition on my file system now, not able to fix it with dosfsck, these are the errors I get trying to fix it. Can't boot windows or ubuntu now.  Think I'm going to have to wipe the entire hard drive but I still don't know if that will fix it.

FAT 1 media ea doesn't match the boot sector's media f8.  You should probably run scandisk.

Bad FAT: unterminated chain for \COMMAND.COM.  You should run dosfsck or scandisk.

Comment: Well that wasn't very nice of boot-repair! Shit. Can you remove the bios-grub flag using gparted, and just have **boot** and **esp**? Hopefully you have a backup of your Ubuntu files from 5 steps ago? If not, boot the Ubuntu Live DVD, mount your /home, and backup your files to an external disk drive or USB flash. At this point, wiping the disk and starting over might be easiest, sorry to say. Make sure that UEFI is **enabled** in your BIOS. Install Windows **FIRST**. Then Ubuntu. Use GPT on the disk. Then go have a drink. Cheers, Al

Comment: I have a backup but I'd like to make another one to be safe, when I try to access the files in my /home it tells me that I don't have permission.

Comment: Because the ownership is different. In terminal, type `gksudo nautilus` (or `sudo nautilus` if that doesn't work). That'll open a FILES window where you can drag off your files in /home. If you restore from backups later, you **may** have to play with file ownership using the **chown** command. Cheers, Al

Comment: Great, I can access them now and that is the most important thing, I'll back them up (again) on monday when I can get a harddrive and let you know how I get on! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just wiped the harddrive and reinstalled everything, currently restoring all my files from backintime. No harm done as far as I can see.

Comment: Let us know your final outcome. And when this is all done and over with, please remember to vote/accept my answer. Cheers, Al

Comment: Back up and running, have all my files back thanks to backintime. Didn't even need my second backup. All fine now

Comment: Great news! Cheers, Al